# Bash pipe to change helm output directory

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to render kubernetes files via a helm chart called `mychart` and write them to a `deploy/` directory. Running the following commands gets me most of the way there:

```
helm template myname mychart/ --output-dir deploy
```

The problem is the k8s files are located at `deploy/mychart/templates/`. I need them at `deploy/`? Other than moving the files after the fact with a separate command (because that's not fun), is there something I can do to make this into a single command? Perhaps by piping the output?

Comment: Certainly not by piping.  Piping output applies to "standard output" which is the text that's normally displayed on your terminal when running the command.  Does not apply to your problem.  Your  best bet is to look at the helm documentation, but I'm thinking you'll probably end up needing to move the files after the fact.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you may want to look at kustomize. The way you are trying to use helm here is basically how kustomize works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following one-liner doesn't use pipe but certainly works, even though it's technically three lines joined into a single line:

```
helm template myname mychart/ --output-dir deploy && \
mv deploy/mychart/templates/* deploy/ && \
rm -rf deploy/mychart/
```